# docker per process routing

Tags: docker, process, routes

I have a docker container running two processes (say process_a and process_b).

I want packets from process_a to be routed out to GW1 and packets from process_b to be routed out to GW2.

Has anyone successfully achieved this?

I have already read and implemented the per process routing using cgroups article at https://www.evolware.org/?p=369.
It works fine for processes on the physical host.  It does not work for processes running inside the docker container. A more detailed explanation for this is at https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/19802 and
https://lists.linuxfoundation.org/pipermail/containers/2014-January/033848.html

Any pointers would be very much appreciated.

thanks,

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic. See [What topics can I ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com) or [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com) would be a better place to ask about advanced Linux routing.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, instead of having 2 processes running in the same container, I'd start 2 instances of the same container running the specific processes and set up the routing for the single instances instead of working out some magic inside the container itself.